# I wrote a program to display the content of an array, but it display with its address

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

I wrote a program that will print the content of an array with odd and another one with an even integers, but when i want to re-print the array it display it with its address in a memory, 
also I want to print the first array with the second array that surround the array one with array 2 which mean that the array one will be in a middle and the array two on the left and right.. 
but i am stuck with re-printing array one,
This is my code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int i,counter[25];
    int j,counter2[25];
    for(i=0;i<=20;i++){
        if(i%2==1)
            continue;
            counter[i]=i;
        cout<<counter[i]<<"  ";
    }
    cout<<"\n";

    for(j=101;j<=115;j++){
        if(j%2==0)
            continue;
        counter2[j]=j;
        cout<<counter2[j]<<"  ";
    }
    cout<<"\n\n";

          for(i=0;i<=20;i++){
            cout<<counter[i]<<"  ";
          }
  return 0;

}
```

the output will be like :

```
0  2  4  6  8  10  12  14  16  18  20
101  103  105  107  109  111  113  115

0  1989701561  2  7208604  4  1990083356  6  1989764433  8  1989701373  10  -1841062257  12  4199040  14  4354336  16  7208680  18  1989725376  20
```

i'm confusing that it prints the address?? should i specify the address for each elements ?

Btw, the second array should start with 101 and above.

Comment: `counter2` has size `25`, you are accessing `counter2[101]` and higher indices in the second loop. This causes undefined behavior and your program could do whatever. Indices of arrays always start at `0` and end at `size-1`. What you see are not addresses, but just non-sense due to the undefined behavior.

Comment: How does `for(j=101;j<=115;j++){` work if `counter2` only has `25` elements? `counter2[j]=j;` is at least `77` elements beyond the end of the array.

Comment: ```counter2``` has size ```25``` that's true, but the value inside it should consist of 101 until 115 , that's why i start the second array with 101 value,, but is it the correct way to do it?

Comment: Value inside of it **can** be `101` to `115` but its *index* **cannot**. Perhaps `for (j = 0; j <= 15; j++) counter2[j] = j + 101;`? You should also initialize your arrays if you are going to iterate over indexes not yet initialized, e.g. `counter[25] = {0};`

Comment: I edited the code which i start the ```counter2``` with ```0``` and i added it with another ```if-statement``` which will ignore the values from ```0``` until ```100```. This will work right ?

Comment: @coder Please don't fix problems in your code related to the question. It makes it impossible for other readers to follow the comments and answers, which are now out-of-sync with the question body. I will revert your edit. You can instead edit in another code block with the changes, keeping the old one as well.

Comment: @walnut noted sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values printed on stdout are not the addresses. They are the values that are stored.

> The first thing you need to know is that every variable gets a garbage value during declaration unless it is not initialized. If you initialize a variable then the variable will carry that value until it is changed by other statements.

- You can see the values of even indices 0, 2, 4, ..., 20 are the same as you set in the first `for` loop.
- But the values at odd indices are not as you expect. Because in the 2nd `for` loop you have iterated through `from 101 to 115` and did not set values at correct indices. Moreover, in the 2nd loop, you stored values in array `counter2`, but finally, you are printing values from array `counter`.

Finally, when you are printing the values from array `counter`, the program outputs the values that are stored at that time. It will be the garbage value if it is not initialized or assigned with other value.

Comment: so how to ignore the garbage values that every variables gets and not print it out?

Comment: should i declare another variable and initialize it to ```zero``` which means it will ignore these ```garbage ``` values ?

Comment: @coder It is completely upto you how you ignore the garbage value. You can do `initializing while declaration` or `assigning with the proper value that you should`. For this question I think you want to set odd values `1 3 5 ... 15` at odd indices `1 3 5 ... 15`, right? If yes, then assing that vaues in array `counter` not `counter2`. And also iterate `from 1 to 15` in the 2nd `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

In your response first two line output is correct for counter and counter2 arrays.

The third output is based on the fact that array on initialization is full of garbage values and nothing else.

lets leave the "counter2" array for once and look at your code for "counter".

i suppose this will be it.

```
int main ()
{
 int i,counter[25];
 int j,counter2[25];
 for(i=0;i<=20;i++){
    if(i%2==1)
        continue;
        counter[i]=i;
    cout<<counter[i]<<"  ";
 }
 cout<<"\n";

      for(i=0;i<=20;i++){
        cout<<counter[i]<<"  ";
      }
  return 0;

 }
```

If you take a closer look to your loop codes

```
 for(i=0;i<=20;i++){
    if(i%2==1)
        continue;
        counter[i]=i;
    cout<<counter[i]<<"  ";
 }
```

what you are doing is checking this condition for "true"

```
    if(i%2==1)
       continue;
```

then on "false" you did is

```
  counter[i]=i;
    cout<<counter[i]<<"  ";
```

here the values are getting inserted to the corresponding value of "i" you are comparing to in the if condition.

in other words

if you are comparing for

```
i=2
in
if(i%2==1)
this will go "false" and to next statement 
counter[i]=i;
i.e. counter[2]=2;
```

you are basically inserting values in the array like this:

```
_ 2 _ 4 _ 6 _ 8 _ 10 ...etc
```

which only modifies specific values in the array leaving the other values untouched.

same thing is true for the second array "counter2" as well.

Comment: okaay for that reason i did ```counter[i]=i``` and it was a mistake. I got it really well now and understood it

Comment: I really appreciate your each explanations to help me out,

Answer (score 0):

You're not printing addresses. You're printing uninitialized integer values. The issue is in your initialization of your array. The reason is that the line
`counter2[j] = j;`
is trying to index the jth element of the array, but j increments from 101 to 115. If you are just trying to get the even numbers from 101 to 115, do something like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j <= 7; j++)
{
    counter2[j] = (100 + 2*(j + 1) - 1);
}
```

When you want to write a for loop to insert elements into an array, you generally want to have the incremented variable represent the index of the element you want to edit.

Comment: can you explain this sentence for me ```counter2[j] = (100 + 2*(j + 1) - 1)``` coz i tried to figure it out how it comes but my brain is really bad in math

Comment: You want j to represent the **index** of the element you are trying to add. That expression `(100 + 2*(j + 1) - 1)` takes that value (an integer from 0 to 7 inclusive) and gives an odd number from 101 to 115 inclusive. If j = 0, then `counter2[j]` will be 101. If j = 1, it will be 103, etc.. Those _are_ your desired values, right?

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++, when you declare an array with *automatic storage duration* using an integer literal, such as:

```
    int i,counter[25];
    int j,counter2[25];
```

The valid indexes for `counter` and `counter2` are `0 <= index < 25`. In your code, despite your `if` statements, when you do:

```
for(j=0;j<=115;j++){
    if(j%2==0)
        continue;
        if(j<101 && j>0)
            continue;
    counter2[j]=j;
    cout<<counter2[j]<<"  ";
}
```

You pass `101` through `115` as the index to:

```
    counter2[j]=j;
    cout<<counter2[j]<<"  ";
```

This exceeds the array bounds and invokes *Undefined Behavior* in your code.

Further, for all indexes that you do not initialize by assigning a value to due to your checks of:

```
    if(i%2==1)
        continue;
```

and

```
    if(j%2==0)
        continue;
```

result in those elements in `counter` and `counter2` not assigned a value holding *indeterminate* values. Any attempt to access the value of a variable with *automatic storage duration* while its value is *indeterminate* results in *Undefined Behavior*. To avoid the problem when skipping indexes, initialize all elements of your array zero at the time the array is declared, e.g.

```
    int i,counter[25] = {0};
    int j,counter2[25] = {0};
```

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

int main (void) {

    int i,counter[25] = {0};
    int j,counter2[25] = {0};

    for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++){
        if (i % 2 == 1)
            continue;
        counter[i]=i;
        std::cout << counter[i] << "  ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    for (j = 0; j <= 15; j++){
        int v = j + 101;
        if (v % 2 == 0)
            continue;
        counter2[j] = v;
        std::cout << counter2[j] << "  ";
    }
    std::cout<<"\n\n";

    for(i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
        std::cout << counter[i] << "  ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

(**note:** including the entire `namespace std` isn't considered good practice. older eyes appreciate code that is reasonably spaced...)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_shift_idx
0  2  4  6  8  10  12  14  16  18  20
101  103  105  107  109  111  113  115

0  0  2  0  4  0  6  0  8  0  10  0  12  0  14  0  16  0  18  0  20
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

**Using Separate Index Variables**

When you have a fixed array and you are going to read some number of values into that array that may/may not be less than the total number of elements in the array, you will want to preserve a separate variable (or counter) holding the number of elements filled. Then when iterating over the array, you can iterate from `0 <= i < filled`.

In your case here, you are using a for loop variable as *values* as well as using the loop variable as an *index*. When you test the *value* and then `continue;` if it isn't what you want, you skip filling the associated *index*. To cure this problem, you simply preserve separate values holding the last filled index in your array. For example:

```
#define NELEM 25    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {

    int counter[NELEM]  = {0},  /* initialize array elements zero */
        counter2[NELEM] = {0},
        ndx1 = 0, ndx2 = 0;     /* separate indexes for counter/counter2 */
```

The variables `ndx1` and `ndx2` are the indexes last filled in `counter` and `counter2`. Now when you loop, you only increment the index when you assign a value to the array, e.g.

```
    for (int i = 0; ndx1 < NELEM; i++) {    /* fill counter w/even values */
        if (i % 2 == 1)
            continue;
        counter[ndx1++] = i;                /* assign value/advance index */
    }
```

(**note:** here all elements are being filled, but you get the idea. You use *independent* variables. One for the *value* you generate and one for the *index* of the array)

Likewise, for the `counter2` array, you could do:

```
    for (int i = 0; ndx2 < NELEM; i++) {    /* fill counter2 w/odd values */
        int v = i + 101;                    /* add 101 to each value */
        if (v % 2 == 0)
            continue;
        counter2[ndx2++] = v;               /* assign value/advance index */
    }
```

A short example using the above that fills the elements of `counter` with *even* values starting at `0` and fills `counter2` with *odd* values starting at `101` and ensures that all values are sequential in each array could be similar to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#define NELEM 25    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {

    int counter[NELEM]  = {0},  /* initialize array elements zero */
        counter2[NELEM] = {0},
        ndx1 = 0, ndx2 = 0;     /* separate indexes for counter/counter2 */

    for (int i = 0; ndx1 < NELEM; i++) {    /* fill counter w/even values */
        if (i % 2 == 1)
            continue;
        counter[ndx1++] = i;                /* assign value/advance index */
    }

    for (int i = 0; ndx2 < NELEM; i++) {    /* fill counter2 w/odd values */
        int v = i + 101;                    /* add 101 to each value */
        if (v % 2 == 0)
            continue;
        counter2[ndx2++] = v;               /* assign value/advance index */
    }

    std::cout<<"counter:\n";                /* output counter values */
    for (int i = 0; i < ndx1; i++) {
        if (i && i % 10 == 0)               /* 10 values per-row */
            std::cout << '\n';
        std::cout << std::setw(4) << counter[i];
    }

    std::cout<<"\n\ncounter2:\n";           /* output counter2 values */
    for (int i = 0; i < ndx2; i++) {
        if (i && i % 10 == 0)               /* 10 values per-row */
            std::cout << '\n';
        std::cout << std::setw(4) << counter2[i];
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_shift_idx2
counter:
   0   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18
  20  22  24  26  28  30  32  34  36  38
  40  42  44  46  48

counter2:
 101 103 105 107 109 111 113 115 117 119
 121 123 125 127 129 131 133 135 137 139
 141 143 145 147 149
```

You can adjust the loop limits to only fill `0 - 20` or `101 - 115` if you like, or you can simply iterate less than `NELEM` times to produce the output you want. Completely up to you. The point being, since you have preserved separate indexes capturing the number of elements in each array that are filled, you can do it either way and you will never iterate past the last filled element in either array.

**Filling Only 1st 8 Odd Values in `counter2`**

For example, if you only wanted to add `101 - 115` to `counter2` and leave the other elements unfilled, you would simply change:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {         /* fill counter2 w/odd values */
        int v = i + 101;                    /* add 101 to each value */
        if (v % 2 == 0)
            continue;
        counter2[ndx2++] = v;               /* assign value/advance index */
    }
```

Now your output for `counter2` would be:

```
counter2:
 101 103 105 107 109 111 113 115
```

Comment: Now I understood every single line that you edit in the code, but the last output which is ```0  0  2  0  4  0  6  0  8  0  10  0  12  0  14  0  16  0  18  0  20 ``` is printing ```0``` between the elements, is that because we initialize the ```counter``` and ```counter2``` arrays with ```{0}``` values , Or?

Comment: Yes, you never assign values to elements `1, 3, 5, 7,...` due to your `if (i % 2 == 1) continue;`. So those indexes are never assigned values by `counter[i]=i;`. Therefore at the end where you loop `for(i = 0; i <= 20; i++)` outputting `counter[i]` you were outputting the *indeterminate* values that just happened to be in memory at that address when the array was declared. (the array memory is not zeroed automatically when the array is declared). You can initialize all values as I have done with `int counter[25] = {0};` to avoid this problem.

Comment: If you want `0, 2, 4, 6, ...` stored in `counter` sequentially, then you need to refactor the logic in your first `for` loop that is filling the `counter` array so you don't leave indexes unset. (you can do this using a second counter as the index which is incremented only when the value is `even`) Give it a shot, if you can't make it work, drop another comment (after you have given it a shot) and I'm happy to help you further.

Comment: I tried to initialize a new counter ```counter3[25]``` and let it equal to ```counter3[i]= counter[i+1]``` and display it, but it couldn't work. I'm really really lost in this step

Comment: Ok, hold on, my fault, you misunderstood. I meant using a separate counter index, not array. I'll give you an example.